# How to fix vertex garbage that I get when opening this file

Tags: mesh

After opening this blend file
https://www.theroyalskies.com/royal-resources

it shows up with all this garbage. What is happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to say, do you know what it is supposed to be?

Comment: This is a human model from here: https://www.theroyalskies.com/royal-resources